# Tagging Docker image (SemVer)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

i need small help. 
What is the best option for tagging docker images. I am looking to make bash script. Is that recommended or is there any different solution? 
I would like to add a way to tag my docker images generated by the jenkins build step.
I need to auto-increment the BuildNumber, but to manually set the MajorVersion and MinorVersion.

I can't find any example related to this. Could you provide me any example to manage my version numbers.

Comment: There are numerous ways to do this. Jenkins provides an environment variable BUILD_NUMBER that increases by build that can be used. Where do you want to "manually set the MajorVersion and MinorVersion"?

Comment: @Behe Thanky very much. Do you have any example. I need this to make [example](https://container-solutions.com/tagging-docker-images-the-right-way/). I want to tag my docker images with this tag  v1.2.3. How to make Automatically tagging for Semantic Versioning ?

Comment: Can you provide the details I asked? How are you setting your major/minor and how are you building and tagging your images? For me, it is unclear what your problem really is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my experience, it's not a very good practice to tag your images with build numbers as part of your image "version". [As stated in SemVer](https://semver.org/), the third part of the version number is the "Patch", representing a non-breaking fix.

The problem with just adding a build number as the patch version is that you aren't necessarily  representing a patch with every build. For example, imagine you're working on a fix (which will get released as a patch version). But you don't nail that fix correctly on your first commit/push to your working branch. That first build will already be a build-number increment, as will any other pushes from other devs to other branches. And this will all depend on how your CI is set up.

If you *need* to put the build number, then you can use your CI build number (I think all CI solutions provide that) and add them to your tag as a fourth element in the semver (e.g.: `2.4.1-2312`, where `2312` is the build number), and once it gets released you can bump the tag to `2.4.2`.

If you want to be compliant with the docker usual practices, you should also tag `2.4.2` as `2.4`, `2` and `latest`, if you're to release it.

My last advise would be to always tag an image with the full SHA of the commit you're building, as there's no easier way for matching an image to a point in time in your codebase.

Comment: you suggest to only tag the images built out of feature branches with build number or SHA1? Once the image is released, the suggested tag  should be `major.minor.patch` only, without the build metadata?

Comment: In all honesty, it's a decision that should be made by the people that own the delivery process. Small projects don't usually need any of this. Larger projects, well. It'll depend. Some folks want to tag with semver, some with DDDD-MM-YY, etc. What I have found _really_ useful is to always tag with the associated commit sha because knowing what code revision an image reflects just by copy/pasting that sha, is priceless and will save you tons of headaches when facing incidents.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add a bit to the accepted answer. According to Semantic Versioning spec (https://semver.org/), the suffix `-foo` in version `x.y.z-foo` is considered a "pre-release version".

Build metadata, e.g. build number, should appended after any pre-release version label as `+build`, e.g. to denote build 33 use `1.2.3-beta1+33` or `1.2.3+33`.

Unfortunately, Docker tags cannot use the `+` character!  Per the `docker tag` [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) (emphasis mine):

> A tag name must be valid ASCII and may contain lowercase and uppercase letters, digits, ***underscores, periods and dashes***. A tag name may not start with a period or a dash and may contain a maximum of 128 characters.

Thus, be aware, you cannot precisely follow semantic versioning and include build info in your docker tag.  Such is life ...

I will follow @gvilarino's advice and simply use a dash `-` to delimit the build number, with or without a pre-release label.  E.g. for build `33` `1.2.3-beta-33` or `1.2.3-33`.