# Pyspark CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, etl, cicd

Curently I'm learning PySpark to perform ETL operation. Here, I have a question how to make a standard pipeline for PySpark script. I'm deploying the PySpark script in Kubernetes with Airflow, I don't know how to make a standard versioning and artifact.

I'm having no idea on this. Earlier I used Talend for ETL, so Talend itself used for pipeline, artifacts and all.

How to perform versioning and artifact preparation, If PySpark script failure, how to rollback to older version?

Answer (score 0):

Use SemVer to tag your PySpark image. Read @gvilarino answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55044480/tagging-docker-image-semver).

Later, if you want to rollback, just update the image tag in the Airflow operator that submit your PySpark job to Kubernetes.